# Add prefix in string if missing in c#

Tags: c#, string, prefix

I have below *multiple* transaction passing to transaction `string`:

```
string transaction = "12345,56789";
```

I want check that if that transaction having **prefix '0'** so how to check that.

e.g.

```
"012345,056789";
```

Suppose if these transactions don't have **prefix '0'** like **"12345,56789"** I want add prefix like this one **"012345,056789"**.

I tried with below code it's wont working for me can any one please guide me how to achieve that.

```
    if(transaction.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        transaction = transaction;
    }
    else
    {
        transaction = "0" + transaction;
    }
```

Comment: the word **trasaction** is not precise here. and use `string.PadLeft`.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, and your logic is correct. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do the strings on both sides of the comma need to be prefixed with `"0"`? I'm not sure why your example code wouldn't work.

Comment: You'll need to do a `Split` on the comma, then iterate the values and add the leading zero, then use `string.Join` to put it back together.

Comment: @michal.materowski Because it doesn't add the zero before the second number "12345,56789" becomes "012345,56789", not "012345,056789"

Comment: split/tokenize your string, then loop through it with @Elias's solution

Comment: You always want 6 digits? Then use Dmitry's String.Split approach but with `Select(part => part.PadLeft(6, '0'))`. The difference is that it just prepends `0`'s if there are less than 6 digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check *each* numeric part of the string, i.e.

```
 "12345,56789"    =>   "012345,056789"
 "012345,56789"   =>   "012345,056789"
 "12345,056789"   =>   "012345,056789"
 "012345,056789"  =>   "012345,056789"
```

You can `Split` the `transaction`, check each part and, finally, `Join` these parts back:

```
using System.Linq;

...

transaction = string.Join(",", transaction
  .Split(',')
  .Select(part => part.StartsWith("0") ? part : $"0{part}"));
```

Another possibility is *regular expressions*:

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 transaction = Regex.Replace(transaction, @"\b[1-9]", "0$&");
```

Here we match every leftmost digit (if it's in `1..9` range) for each part (note `\b` for word border) and add `0` prefix: in `"0$&"` `0` is `0` and `$&` stands for the entire match.

Comment: transaction = Regex.Replace(transaction, @"\b[1-9]", "0$&"); - is it means if transaction sting if have any character it will not add prefix "0" it only add if its have numeric value between [1-9] ?

Comment: @Sanjay Nakate: yes, if transaction name starts with *word* character, e.g. `a123` it will **not** be converted (into `a0123`) since `a` will not be matched with *word boundary* `\b`.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: now it should work**

you can handle a string like a charakter array like:

```
string transactionid  = "12345,56789";
string transactionid_split = transactionid.split(',');

if(transactionid_split[0][0] != "0")
transactionid_split[0] = "0" +  transactionid_split[0];

if(transactionid_split[1][0] != "0")
transactionid_split[1]  = "0" + transactionid_split[1];

transactionid = transactionid_split[0] + "," + transactionid_split[1]
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `StartsWith`, that way you can use the same code for prefixes of arbitrary length.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. still no 0 before the part after the comma.

Comment: Also this isn't going to function any differently from what they already have.

Comment: Your code now assumes there is exactly one comma which might be the case but it's better to have an iterative solution to avoid index out of range exceptions and not updating all the numbers if something like "12345,56789,22222" is possible.

Comment: @juharr yea you right, its only right if its everytime the same case. In other cases the solution of Dimitry is perfect

Comment: the variable names are dazzling my eyes.

Comment: @LeiYang its only for demonstration :) xD

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting code for each part, write a function: `string EnsureZeroSuffix(string s) => (s[0] != '0') ? "0" + s : s;`  Then the answer is simply: `var parts = transactionid.split(','); transactionid = EnsureZeroSuffix(parts[0]) + "," + EnsureZeroSuffix(parts[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming the format of the `transaction` `string` is always going to be two numbers separated by a comma**, you can use [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___) to split the string, check for the prefix of `"0"`, add it if it is missing, then put the `strings` back together.

Something like...

```
var transaction = "12345,56789";

var parts = transaction.Split(',');

// You'd want to check that 0 and 1 are valid indexes, probably.
if (!parts[0].StartsWith("0"))
{
   parts[0] = "0" + parts[0];
}
if (!parts[1].StartsWith("0"))
{
   parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
}
transaction = $"{parts[0]},{parts[1]}";
```

You could also iterate through `parts` if `transaction` could potentially have more than one comma.